# How do I place a widget in the center of the screen while ignoring column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There is a widget (for example text). In the real example it comes after another widget in Column. How to put it in the center of the screen? As I understand it, the Column does not. How can this be done? Or are there other ways to specify the location of items?
[image]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? maybe there is some better way

Answer (score 1):

Column takes all the available space of the parent and by default aligns the items to start

You can change fix this changes the `MainAxisAlignment` to `center`.

```
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("test"),
  ],
),
```

---

or changing parents height and move it to the center (be careful if you add many items it will cause overflow)

```
child: Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 25,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("test"),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: For example, now I need this:
First widget (at the top left)
Second widget (at the center of screen)
Third widget (at the bottom center)
How to do This?

Comment: You can check the docs to see how Column works. In this case if you want to align three Widgets in column this way you just need `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` . The other solution is to Wrap the middle widget with `Expanded`

Answer (score 0):

Using Stack widget you can do it:

```
var textEmpty = Text("Some Text");

Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              ,margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0)
              ,child:  Center(child: textEmpty, ),)],),
          listView,
 ]);
```

Use `Center` Wigdet instead of `Container`. Hope this helps!

Comment: If I use stack, I think, it will be more difficult to put new widgets after this centered widget. Or no?

Comment: if more than one widget then you have to manage according to that. Stack is pretty easy way to do that. we just need to calculate proportional height & width.

Comment: I know this is a little silly question, but how to put Widgets in a stack without losing positionality? (Sorry for my English)

Comment: @ИванПетрухин plz [check](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) this

Comment: I can not yet :\
Sorry, one more question:
For example, now I need this:
First widget (at the top left)
Second widget (at the center of screen)
Third widget (at the bottom center)
How to do This?

Comment: @ИванПетрухин, i give you hint do it by yourself, Inside `Column` there is 3 `Container` each container having 3 different `Stack` do as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

No worries where it comes from. It depends on the view where you have added it.

If you want to show in the center then just use **Center widget**

If you want to use **Container widget** then, you have to add the width and height both to **double.infinite**

If you want to use it in the same widget then you can use the **Stack widget** as well.

It totally depends on the requirement of the view and in which way you are tried to implement it.